# Built in iPhone controls animating in slow motion

Tags: iphone, animation, nib, motion

I am experiencing a very strange problem where the built in controls in my iPhone app are animating in slow motion.  These are controls that I have not implemented, like the TopBar on a ViewController.  In this case, the title and buttons all, slowly move from the outer edge of the screen to their designated final destinations.  It's like my app has slowed down and is showing me a debug version so I can see how the various pieces all move into place. I am embedding an link to an animation I created showing the problem.

http://icandy.ricohinnovations.com/images/navbar_animation_problem.gif

I have found that, in some cases, I have fixed the issue by removing a .xib file from the project.  But making changes to the same .xib file have not worked. Does this mean there could be an issue with one or more of my .xib files?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

Comment: +1 for not directly embedding the 1MB gif in the post.